# Clojure multiline regular expression

Tags: regex, clojure

I'm trying to test a string for a basic html pattern and although I use the m (multiline) modifier it only works when the string is a 1-liner

```
(re-find #"(?im)^<html>.*<body>.*</body>.*</html>" c))
```

Fails:

```
"<html>   <body>   sad   </body> 
     </html>"
```

Works:

```
"<html>   <body>   sad   </body>      </html>"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll just leave it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Clojure programmer, but I think this problem is independent of the language.

When multi-line mode is enabled, the interpretation of the caret `^` and the dollar `$` changes like this: Instead of matching the beginning and end *of the entire input string*, they match the beginning and the end *of each line in the input string*. This is - as far as I can see - not what you want/need.

What you want is for your `.*`s to match newlines (what they don't do by default) and this can be done by enabling the single-line mode (aka dot-all mode). So this means:

```
(re-find #"(?is)^<html>.*<body>.*</body>.*</html>" c))
```

You can also verify this on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?33s9t).

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the `(?s)` "dotall mode" [switch](http://nakkaya.com/2009/10/25/regular-expressions-in-clojure/).

Example:

```
user=> (re-find #"\d{3}.\d{3}" "123\n456")    
nil

user=> (re-find #"(?s)\d{3}.\d{3}" "123\n456")
"123\n456"
```

The `(?m)` switch is deceptively named -- it changes what the `^` and `$` anchors do, allowing them to also match start-of-line and end-of-line, respectively -- which is not want you want.

Comment: Thanks Matt! Other might find http://nakkaya.com/2009/10/25/regular-expressions-in-clojure/ useful, too.